# How to get serial number of my android phone in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using android management api. Now, I want to map my device with an identifier to android management api. Like, I am getting a list of devices from google. But I don't know which device is that. So, to identify that, I need something from this response:

```
"hardwareInfo": {
    "brand": "Lenovo",
    "hardware": "*****",
    "deviceBasebandVersion": "****************",
    "manufacturer": "LENOVO",
    "serialNumber": "HA1*****",
    "model": "Lenovo TB-7305X"
},
```

which can be used for mapping. Now, to get device id, I used `device_info_plus`. But it didn't worked. So, I created a method channel and wrote some kotlin code, it also didn't work. Here is the function:

```
fun getSerialNumber(): String {
        var serialNumber: String?
        try {
            val c = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties")
            val get = c.getMethod("get", String::class.java)
            serialNumber = get.invoke(c, "gsm.sn1") as String
            if (serialNumber == "") serialNumber = get.invoke(c, "ril.serialnumber") as String
            if (serialNumber == "") serialNumber = get.invoke(c, "ro.serialno") as String
            if (serialNumber == "") serialNumber = get.invoke(c, "sys.serialnumber") as String
            if (serialNumber == "") serialNumber = get.invoke(c, "ro.boot.serialno") as String
            if (serialNumber == "") serialNumber = get.invoke(c, "ro.kernel.androidboot.serialno") as String
            if (serialNumber == "") {
                serialNumber = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    Build.getSerial()
                } else {
                    Build.SERIAL
                }
            }

            // If none of the methods above worked
            if (serialNumber == "") serialNumber = null
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            serialNumber = null
        }
        if (!serialNumber.isNullOrEmpty() && serialNumber != Build.UNKNOWN) {
            return serialNumber
        }
        return "TEMP12345678"
    }
```

I copied this from stack overflow only (I have no idea about Kotlin lol), but it's not working. If anyone who knows kotlin and see something wrong with the function, please help me out and correct this function.

I added these permissions in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE " />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE" />
```

And the android version is 11, though a solution which can work with all versions will be much much appreciated.

Comment: In general, the vendors are making it harder to identify device IDs because it breaks things when customers want to upgrade to a new phone.  Instead, you should just store a UUID into your local storage on first usage.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and use [`device_info_plus`](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus)

Getting device info

```
  deviceInformation() async {
    DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
      print('Serial No : ${androidInfo.id}');
      return androidInfo.id;
    } else {
      IosDeviceInfo iosInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
      return iosInfo.identifierForVendor;
    }
  }
```

Create method for getting serial no

```
String appVersion = '';
device() async {
    appVersion = await  deviceInformation();
  }
```

pass above method inside init() state method

```
@override
  void initState() {
    device();
    super.initState();
  }
```

UI:

```
Text('Serial No of Current Device : $appVersion',),
```

Console Output - `Serial No : SE1A.211212.001.B1`

result screen -> [image]

Comment: Your device has which version of android?

Comment: Version - Android 13